# Tableau. How to get access to a field value of other record in calculated field?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

In Tableau I need to create new calculated field.
This field should be a sum of other records fields (see screenshot).

[image]

I'm trying to do the following:

```
IF [Town1] = "Mullingar.Co..." AND [Trip Type1] = "Holiday Trips"

THEN
    IF [Town1] = "Mullingar.Co..."
       AND [Trip Type1] = "Holiday Trips"
       AND [Region1] = 2
    THEN [Trip Count1] END
    +
    IF [Town1] = "Mullingar.Co..."
       AND [Trip Type1] = "Holiday Trips"
       AND [Region1] = 3
    THEN [Trip Count1] END
    +
    IF [Town1] = "Mullingar.Co..."
       AND [Trip Type1] = "Holiday Trips"
       AND [Region1] = 4
    THEN [Trip Count1] END
END
```

But it returns NULL always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a LOD expression using FIXED. Something in the lines of 
{FIXED [Town1]:SUM([Trip Count1])}